# How can I prefill "phone number" in Calendly via JavaScript? the "location" field does not work

Tags: javascript, calendly

I have a "phone call, one on one" event type in Calendly that I would like to provide a customized embed script with. Based on documentation I found out that the `location` parameter/field can be used to prefill phone number via the URL, but it's not working for this kind of embed code, it is not prefilling the inline widget. Everything else gets in and fills the Calendly widget. Does anyone know how to do this prefill for the phone number field?

```
                     Calendly.initInlineWidget({
                        url: 'https://calendly.com/<company_name>/free-consultation-30-mins',
                        parentElement: document.getElementById('calendly-widget'),
                        prefill: {
                            name: form.fname + ' ' + form.lname,
                            email: vm.form.email,
                            location: '8184481727',
                            customAnswers: {
                                a1: form.other_info,
                                a2: form.credit_card_debt, // cc debt
                                a3: form.irs_debt, // how much tax debt,
                                a4: form.unfiled_returns, // how many unfiled tax returns
                                a5: form.state // which state
                            }
                        },
                        utm: {}
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I work at Calendly. Looks like this is a bug in our embed code, you should be able to prefill the location via the `prefill` object. I'll post back when it's fixed, but the recommended workaround for the time being is to append the `location` parameter directly to the booking URL, bypassing the `prefill` object:

```js
Calendly.initInlineWidget({
    url: 'https://calendly.com/<company_name>/free-consultation-30-mins?location=8184481727',
    parentElement: document.getElementById('calendly-widget'),
    prefill: {
        name: form.fname + ' ' + form.lname,
        email: vm.form.email,
        customAnswers: {
            a1: form.other_info,
            a2: form.credit_card_debt, // cc debt
            a3: form.irs_debt, // how much tax debt,
            a4: form.unfiled_returns, // how many unfiled tax returns
            a5: form.state // which state
        }
    },
    utm: {}
});
```

Comment: @Dimitry Have you guys added "location" in the array at the GetPrefillParams function `this.options.prefill, ["name", "firstName", "lastName", "email"])` already?

Comment: @Nilebac no, but the issue is being tracked internally. I'll update this post as soon as there are news.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked at the calendly embed javascript file, unminified it and found this :

```
getPrefillParams() {
    if (!this.options.prefill) return [];
    const t = i(this.options.prefill, ["name", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "location"]),
        n = e(t, (t, e) => o(e));
    if (this.options.prefill.customAnswers) {
        const t = this.options.prefill.customAnswers;
        Object.entries(t).forEach((t) => {
            let [e, r] = t;
            e.match(/^a\d{1,2}$/) && (n[e] = r);
        });
    }
    return n;
}
```

I added "location" on the array after "email" because it was missing and it worked. The phone number was prefilled.

Comment: hi, could you provide more clarity on this answer? I'm facing the same issue now. How do I add this code to my javascript file?

Comment: I think Nilebac may have modified Calendly's JavaScript and hosted it himself. If you don't want to do it, you can instead append the `location` query parameter directly to the booking URL. Let me illustrate in a separate answer.